# Sharepoint Out of the box Approval Workflow Approve/Reject comments issue when programmatically altering it

Tags: development, workflow

This Question already asked on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752534/sharepoint-out-of-the-box-approval-workflow-approve-reject-comments-issue-when-p) but couldn't found solution. Hope this is the correct place to ask whether this can be done programmatically or alternative approaches.

Need to update comments field not the `ModerationInformation.Comment`.

Thanks in advance.